# SELECT from multiple tables in separate rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a search function on my site where you can search both users and locations. I'm trying to make it to get all of the results in one query, but it returns the results in one row.

**SQL**

```
SELECT users.f_name, users.l_name, users.id, locations.name, locations.id
FROM users, locations
WHERE CONCAT(f_name, ' ', l_name) LIKE '%k%' OR name LIKE '%k%';
```

However, this is the structure it returns:

```
*---------*----------*------*------------*-----*
| f_name  |  l_name  |  id  |    name    | id  |
*---------*----------*------*------------*-----*
|  Joe    |  Smith   |   1  |  Location  |  1  |
*---------*----------*-------------------*-----*
etc.
```

I want it to return this:

```
*---------*----------*------*------------*--------*
| f_name  |  l_name  |  id  |    name    |   id   |
*---------*----------*------*------------*--------*
|  Joe    |  Smith   |   1  |    NULL    |  NULL  |
|  NULL   |   NULL   | NULL |  Location  |    1   |
*---------*----------*------*------------*--------*
```

My only other option is to make two separate queries and combine the results. It seems kind of inefficient to do that, and since it's being dynamically loaded with ajax, I want this to be as fast as possible.

What's the best way to do this?

## EDIT

The table structure is like this:

```
users
*---------*----------*------*
| f_name  |  l_name  |  id  |
*---------*----------*------*

locations
*-------*------*
| name  |  id  |
*-------*------*
```

Comment: Curious, why do you want the return like that? Why not parse it in whatever application you're using

Comment: @dustytrash, what do you mean? (I'm not really an SQL expert)

Comment: You mentioned you have a function on your site which needs this. Why not just parse the results before displaying them, in whatever language you're using (PHP, JavaScript etc)?

Comment: @Parfait, that's just the test value I was using.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure why you would want the data like this, but this will do it for you in 1 query.

Using the UNION the data types and column names need to be the same in matching columns.

```
SELECT users.f_name, users.l_name, users.id AS UserID, NULL AS name, NULL AS LocationId
FROM users
WHERE CONCAT(f_name, ' ', l_name) LIKE '%k%' 
UNION ALL 
SELECT NULL AS f_name, NULL AS l_name, NULL AS Userid, locations.name, locations.id AS LocationId
FROM locations 
WHERE name LIKE '%k%'
```

Comment: This gets a `#1054 - Unknown column 'name' in 'where clause'` error in phpMyAdmin. I'm not sure you have the table structure right, see my edited question.

Comment: @Brad ... move the second `WHERE` condition `name LIKE '%k%'` to last `SELECT` statement.

Comment: @YaakovAinspan I updated the code, as Parfait said I had the where clause partilly incorrect, its fixed now

Answer (score 0):

`union all` should do what you want:

```
select u.f_name, u.l_name, u.id, NULL as name, NULL as id
from users u
where CONCAT(f_name, ' ', l_name) like '%k%';
union all
select null, null, null, l.name, l.id
from locations l
where l.name LIKE '%k%';
```